# intersection of two height 2 primes must contain a non-zero prime?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, prime-ideals, noetherian

I saw in some contexts the following statement, which I do not have a reference for this:

"Kaplansky asked if in a Noetherian domain the intersection
of two height 2 primes must contain a non-zero prime."

What is the motivation of this question?
Can you please give a reference?

Thank you.

Comment: Google "Mcadam, A Noetherian example" for a counter example. The question is interesting because it asks if two irreducible codimension 2 subsets of the spectrum are contained in a single irreducible codimension 1 subset. If $X$ is an algebraic surface (over an algebraically closed field for example), then any two closed points are contained in an irreducible curve lying on $X$.